# Rust : Serialize the list of structs and write in a file in BSON format and deserialize back to struct

Tags: rust, struct, bson, serde

I am trying to convert list of structs and write in a  file in BSON format and deserialize back to struct . I am using

```
bson = { version="2.6.0" }
```

crate . I converted my list of structs to Bson , and then tried finding any way to convert the bson to vec[u8] , but didn't find any .

I need to store bson in their binary format only to a specific file.

Here is the code snippet

```rust
use std::{fs::File, io::Write};

use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug,Serialize,Deserialize)]
struct Bison {
    name: String,
    age: u16,
    place: String,
    phone: u16,
}

pub fn check_bson() {
    let mut bisons: Vec<Bison> = Vec::with_capacity(1000);
    for i in 1..1001 {
        bisons.push(Bison {
            name: format!("Name {}", i),
            age: i as u16,
            place: format!("Place {}", i),
            phone: i as u16,
        });
    }

    let mut file = File::create("data.bson").expect("Failed to create file");

    let s = bson::to_bson(&bisons).unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`BSON`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/enum.Bson.html) enum only contains the document tree. In order to get a `Vec<u8>` you will need to actually encode the [`Document`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/struct.Document.html) which can be done like so:

```rust
use bson::{SerializerOptions, Document};
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug,Serialize,Deserialize)]
struct Bison {
    name: String,
    age: u16,
    place: String,
    phone: u16,
}

pub fn check_bson() {
    let mut bisons: Vec<Bison> = Vec::with_capacity(1000);
    for i in 1..1001 {
        bisons.push(Bison {
            name: format!("Name {}", i),
            age: i as u16,
            place: format!("Place {}", i),
            phone: i as u16,
        });
    }

    let options = SerializerOptions::builder().human_readable(false).build();
    let bson = bson::to_bson_with_options(&bisons, options).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", bson);

    let mut doc = Document::new();
    doc.insert("array".to_string(), bson);

    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    doc.to_writer(&mut buf).unwrap();

    std::fs::write("data.bson", buf).expect("Failed to create file");
}
```

Please note, that we had to give a name to the array (in this case I chose "array"), because an [`Array`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/enum.Bson.html#variant.Array) itself is a non-[`Document`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/struct.Document.html) type and can thus not be used at the top level.

Alternatively you can use [`to_vec`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/fn.to_vec.html), but you will also have to consider that the top-level element can not be a BSON [`Array`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/type.Array.html), so you will have to wrap it like shown below:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Bison {
    name: String,
    age: u16,
    place: String,
    phone: u16,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct RootElement {
    array: Vec<Bison>,
}

pub fn check_bson() {
    let mut bisons: Vec<Bison> = Vec::with_capacity(1000);
    for i in 1..1001 {
        bisons.push(Bison {
            name: format!("Name {}", i),
            age: i as u16,
            place: format!("Place {}", i),
            phone: i as u16,
        });
    }

    // The root element of a BSON document can not be an array (e.g. a Vec in rust).
    let data = RootElement {
        array: bisons
    };

    let buf = bson::to_vec(&data).unwrap();
    std::fs::write("data.bson", buf).expect("Failed to create file");
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you are wrong. Clippy does not warn in both of the code snippets about anything and there is not even a `write_all` function in [`std::fs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/index.html).

Comment: @Finomnis `std::fs::write` already [does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/fs.rs.html#325-330) `write_all` under the hood.

Comment: My bad, ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The top level of your bson file has to be a [`Document`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/struct.Document.html). A `Vec` is sadly not compatible with top level bison usage. It has to be something that resembles a key-value mapping, like a `HashMap` or a `struct`.

The easiest way to achieve that is to use a `struct` as the top level object. The actual call to convert it to binary is [`bson::to_vec`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/fn.to_vec.html):

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::fs::File;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Bison {
    name: String,
    age: u16,
    place: String,
    phone: u16,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct BisonDoc {
    bisons: Vec<Bison>,
}

pub fn main() {
    // Write to file
    {
        let mut bisons_doc = BisonDoc {
            bisons: Vec::with_capacity(3),
        };
        for i in 1..=3 {
            bisons_doc.bisons.push(Bison {
                name: format!("Name {}", i),
                age: i as u16,
                place: format!("Place {}", i),
                phone: i as u16,
            });
        }

        let binary_data = bson::to_vec(&bisons_doc).expect("Unable to create bison data");

        std::fs::write("data.bson", binary_data).expect("Failed to write bson file");
    }

    // Read from file
    {
        let file = File::open("data.bson").expect("Unable to open file");
        let bisons: BisonDoc = bson::from_reader(file).expect("Error while reading bson data");

        println!("{:#?}", bisons);
    }
}
```

```
BisonDoc {
    bisons: [
        Bison {
            name: "Name 1",
            age: 1,
            place: "Place 1",
            phone: 1,
        },
        Bison {
            name: "Name 2",
            age: 2,
            place: "Place 2",
            phone: 2,
        },
        Bison {
            name: "Name 3",
            age: 3,
            place: "Place 3",
            phone: 3,
        },
    ],
}
```